# How do I modify_spanning_header() across specific stats in a gtsummary::tbl_strata()?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm working with a tbl_summary with which I want to make a tbl_strata table in order to make the table with two "by" arguments.
However, when I do this, I cannot figure out how to transfer all my modifications (modify_header, modify_spanning_header, and so on) in the tbl_summary table onto the new tbl_strata table.

For the sake of reproducibility, here's an example of my problem illustrated with the trial data:

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl_strata_ex1 <-
  trial %>%
  dplyr::select(age, grade, stage, trt) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(grade = paste("Grade", grade)) %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_strata(
    strata = grade,
    .tbl_fun =
      ~ .x %>%
      gtsummary::tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "ifany") %>%
      gtsummary::modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Treatment type**")
  )
```

When I run the above code, Rstudio does not throw any error, but it also **does not** create the spanning header as it does in the tbl_summary alone. It just does nothing. I want to create one header "Treatment Type" spanning over all of the three "Drug A   Drug B" sections.

I first tried with gtsummary::modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1_1", "stat_2_1", "stat_1_2", "stat_2_2", "stat_1_3", "stat_2_3" ~ "**Treatment type**"), as these "stats" are the ones I find in the dataframe for the table body. However, inputting this instead of all_stat_cols() in modify_spanning_header() throws this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `tbl = switch(...)`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! Error in `... or update=` argument input. Select from ‘variable’, ‘row_type’, ‘label’, ‘n’,
  ‘var_type’, ‘var_label’, ‘stat_1’, ‘stat_2’
```

How does one add modify_spanning_header, or modify_header, other elements from the tbl_summary that one wants to be preserved in the tbl_strata?

I really hope someone might be able to help me, as this is giving me quite the headache! ;-)

Comment: The strata function adds a spanning header, you you'll need to move this command to the end, after the strata call. gtsummary::modify_spanning_header

Comment: Thank you very much for a swift and indeed very useful reply! Solved it :)